# As the admin user, destroy a few sample users through the web interface. What are the corresponding entries in the server log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Again, a question about Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial.
Above is an exercise to destroy users.
My question is: where is the 'server log', and how can I see the entries?

In my application there is a 'development.log' and a 'test.log', but I see no server log.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The server log is just a generic term and can refer to `log/development.log` for applications running locally or `log/production.log` for applications running in production. You can `tail -f log/development.log` to see the entries when working through the tutorial locally.

Comment: Yes, I have seen it now; `tail -f log/development.log` shows the latest entries!